# Is it possible to continue playing a video?

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a video file being transferred to my server.  As soon as the video starts arriving I begin playing the video via the "video" html5 tag.  However, if there is any sort of pause in the transfer of the video, the video stops playing (as expected.)  Is there any way (I expect it would be via javascript), to automatically start playing the video where it left off as more of the video bits arrive on the server?  I've noticed, if I add the "controls" and the video pauses, hitting the "play" button, starts the video from the beginning again.  I just want it to continue playing where it left off.  Is that possible?

Comment: I think Javascript has to be written to either handle the "onstalled" or "onwaiting" events.

Answer (score 0):

How about set  autoplay

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay>
  <source
      src="http://yourSite.com/yourPath/video.webm"
      type='video/webm'>
  <source
      src="http://yourSite.com/yourPath/video.ogg"
      type='video/ogg'>
  <source
      src="http://yourSite.com/yourPath/video.mp4"
      type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes in attributes of the `source` element.

Comment: autoplay doesn't force it to continue.  It just pauses.  Autoplay just automatically starts the video playing when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "loop" attribute to your video element like so:

```
<video loop>
  <source
      src=videos/video.webm
      type=video/webm>
  <source
      src=videos/video.ogg
      type=video/ogg>
  <source
      src=videos/video.mp4
      type=video/mp4>
</video>
```

Comment: Nope...loop just basically takes the portion of the video that was cached when it stopped and continuously replays the portion of the video.  I want it to continue playing where it left off as more of the video file is copied and the video file becomes larger.